# Libgdx - camera.unproject is not fixing my coordinates

Tags: camera, libgdx, project

The following code gives me very strange y coordinates.

```
10-18 00:13:36.834  30543-30567/com.xxxx.yyyy.android I/x﹕ 137.4782
10-18 00:13:36.834  30543-30567/com.xxxx.yyyy.android I/y﹕ -1984.2426
10-18 00:13:36.835  30543-30567/com.xxxx.yyyy.android I/ux﹕ 91.65213
10-18 00:13:36.835  30543-30567/com.xxxx.yyyy.android I/uy﹕ -1984.2426
```

I imagine I set up everything wrong rather than do it wrong while running?
The camera.unproject call should take care of all remapping from screen coordinates to game coordinates, shouldn't it? Or do i have to scale and invert before unprojecting?

```
package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Camera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;


public class LetterActor extends Actor
{
    private Texture texture;
    private Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3();
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean unproject = true;

    public LetterActor(Texture letterTexture, Camera theCamera)
    {
        texture = letterTexture;
        camera = theCamera;

        touchPosition.set(240, 800, 0);
        camera.unproject(touchPosition);
        setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

        setSize(texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());

        addListener(new InputListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

                logPositions(x, y, touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

                logPositions(x, y, touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
            }

            @Override
            public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
            {
                touchPosition.set(x, y, 0);
                if (unproject)
                {
                    camera.unproject(touchPosition);
                }
                setPosition(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);

                logPositions(x, y, touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
            }
        });
    }

    private void screenTo()
    {

    }

    private void logPositions(float x, float y,float ux, float uy)
    {
        Gdx.app.log("x", Float.toString(x));
        Gdx.app.log("y", Float.toString(y));
        Gdx.app.log("ux", Float.toString(ux));
        Gdx.app.log("uy", Float.toString(y));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha)
    {
        batch.draw(texture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {}
}



package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.ExtendViewport;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

public class WordPuzzle extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    private final static float VIRTUAL_WIDTH = 480;
    private final static float VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = 800;

    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private FitViewport viewport;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
        camera.setToOrtho(false, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);

        viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, camera);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setViewport(viewport);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Texture[] textures = LetterLoader.loadLetters();
        for (int i = 0; i < textures.length; i++)
        {
            LetterActor letterActor = new LetterActor(textures[i], camera);
            letterActor.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
            stage.addActor(letterActor);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }


    @Override public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override public void dispose()
    {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}



package com.xxxx.yyyy;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class LetterLoader {

    public static Texture[] loadLetters()
    {
        Texture[] letters = new Texture[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            char letter = (char) (i + 65);
            letters[i] = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bigletters/" + letter + ".png"));
        }

        return letters;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the touch position (x, y) you get from the input listener are already the correct coordinates.

---

Concerning your output, you actually print y two times, but call it uy the second time:

```java
Gdx.app.log("uy", Float.toString(y));
```

---

If `touchPosition.set(240, 800, 0);` is in screen coordinates, then you need to unproject them, but

```java
camera.unproject(touchPosition);
```

assumes that your camera fills the whole screen, thus it calls internally:

```java
unproject(screenCoords, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Since you use a virtual size, this is wrong. The most simple solution would be to use the unproject method from the viewport that you are using:

```java
viewport.unproject(touchPosition);
```

This will call the camera unproject method with the correct parameters automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Stage and InputListener, the coordinates you get in `touchDown` and the related methods are already in world coordinates, so it doesn't make sense to unproject them. You can use the x and y directly.

Also (although this is irrelevant to InputListener), `camera.unproject` assumes a Viewport that fills the screen, which is not true of FitViewport, which you're using. If you are using a Viewport class, you need to use `viewport.unproject` instead of `camera.unproject`, so it takes the black bars into account.

But you only need to worry about unprojecting for stuff not related to the Stage.